# Solve for $x$ in $-\arctan(0.3x)-2x=-180^{\circ}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I solve for $x$ in the following:
 $$-\arctan(0.3x)-2x=-180^{\circ} \qquad ?$$ 
I tried
\begin{align}
\arctan(0.3x)&=180^{\circ}-2x \\
0.3x&=\tan(180^{\circ}-2x)\\
\end{align}
With the identity $\tan(\alpha\pm\beta)=\frac{\tan\alpha\pm\tan\beta}{1\mp\tan\alpha \tan \beta }$, I have
\begin{align}
0.3x&=\tan(180^{\circ}-2x)\\
&=\frac{\tan 180^{\circ}- \tan 2x}{1+\tan 180^{\circ} \, \tan 2x}\\
&=-\tan 2x
\end{align}
So I'm stuck with $0.3x=-\tan 2x$, is it correct? How should I proceed?

Comment: You cannot go further analytically.

Comment: a trivial solution is $x=0$

Comment: $x=\tan x$ is transcendental, meaning the solution cannot be expressed in a finite sequence of algebraic operations. The best you can do is approximate

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=\tan(2x) + 0.3x$$ and apply Newton's method to approximate zero's of $f(x).$

Comment: Make sure to graph the two functions first do you have a general idea of where the solutions are.